# Java servlet not finding my index.jsp when running tomcat in intellij

Tags: java, maven, servlets, intellij-idea

I using intellij.

Ok, tomcat is running, everything is okay but aways give me a 404 error.

my web.xml is in webcontent folder in the root of the project.
projectfolder/WebContent/WEB-INF

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">

<display-name>WebTicket</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and My page is in:
projectfolder/WebContent

Well in the project properties, the project facet is web.

I using a servle + maven.

Any Ideia in how to solve it?

the problem is problably in the folder structure, I read somewhere if a change the project facet it should be solved, but how to do that?

Comment: When some code, invoked by entering a URL, causes an error, and you want help with that, post the code, post the URL, and post the exact and complete error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Well. 
I created the project as Dynamic Web Module to 2.5 and changed to 4.0

The default folder for Web resources in 2.5 is projectfolder/src/main/webapp

in 4.0 is projectfolder/WebContent

When I changed the facet in project proprierties in the eclipse, the old configuration remained.

in intellij just go in **file>project structure**

facets tab, select web module and change Web Resources folder.